Dynamic sensor fustion in robot localization
Issue:
I am using Robot Localization with ROS 2 and integrating data from multiple sensors into the Extended Kalman Filter (EKF). My concern is about handling situations where one of the sensors loses data temporarily or permanently.
Question:
Can I dynamically adjust sensor configurations using ROS 2 parameter server or ros2 param set cli command? For example, if one sensor loses data, can I modify the parameter /ekf_filter_node_map pose1_config to exclude the affected sensor's data from the EKF fusion? Here’s an example command:
ros2 param set /ekf_filter_node_map pose1_config "[false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]"

If dynamic adjustment isn't feasible, what are the recommended approaches? Should I consider setting the covariance of the affected sensor's data to infinity to effectively exclude it from the fusion process?

Can you provide a more concrete example? What sensor is losing data temporarily? Why not just prevent it from publishing in that time? Do you have any other sensors?
I would provide a full config and sample sensor messages, as well as a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to achieve.
